# How do I compile a Go program against both source code and binary-only packages?

Tags: go

Background: I wrote a feature(in packageA) and don't want anyone see my code. So I installed it into .a file(packageA.a). I use it by below method:

```
package main  
import packageA  
func main(){  
    packageA.Run()  
}
```

Then I do

`go tool compile -I lib/ main.go

    go tool link -o main -L main.o`

It can work.

But when I do this it doesn't work.
I wrote another feature(packageB) in `$GOPATH/src/project/packageB`
and update main.go

```
// main.go
package main
import (
    "packageA"
    _ "project/packageB"
)

func main(){
    packageA.Run()
}
```

exec
`go tool compile -I lib/ main.go`

but error
`can't find import "packageB"`

my directory layout

```
project  
     main.go  
     lib/  
        packageA.a  
     packageB  
        xxx.go
```

Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that? go tool compile how to import .a file and source code?

Thanks sincerely in advance.

Comment: "packageB" is not a valid package name. You need to use the full path to the package.

Comment: Please provide your current directory layout.

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks. But I use full path I still get this error.

Comment: @Venantius I have updated my question adding my directory. Thank you!

Comment: You can't install packageA as packageA.a file, where did you get that information? There are [Binary Only Packages](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Binary_Only_Packages) that can be used in a limited sense, but this isn't how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question, and required a bit of research on my part to answer.

I'm going to assume that your question is really just a minimal example for reproduction purposes, and that your *REAL* question is: "How do I compile a Go program against both source code and [binary-only packages](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Binary_Only_Packages)?"

Let's walk through this step by step

**Phase 1: Generating your binary-only package.**

You probably already have the binary-only package, so you can skip this step if you want, but it's helpful for setting context.

First, let's make sure your package names actually are correct for the folder structure. That means main.go has the following imports:

```
import (
    "project/packageA"
    "project/packageB"
)
```

Similarly, the source code in packageB (which in your example is dependent on packageA) uses `import "project/packageB"`

So what you want to have originally is a structure that looks like this:

```
$GOPATH/
  src/
    project/
      main.go
      packageA
        xxx.go
      packageB
        xxx.go
```

And you want to compile packageA so that it's just a static binary. You can do this very simply by running `go install .` from the `packageA` directory.

You now have the following structure:

```
$GOPATH/
  pkg/
    $ARCH/
      project/
        packageA.a
  src/
    project/
      main.go
      packageA
        xxx.go
      packageB
        xxx.go
```

**Phase 2: Building main.go without the Go source for packageA**

Your problem now is: *how do I tell the Go compiler to look for **both** go source files in `src` **and** linked binaries in `pkg`?*

The catch here is that if you just delete packageA, the Go compiler toolchain will be confused - it assumes by default that missing Go source code means the build has failed. So what you can do as of Go 1.7 is to provide a build flag to the compiler *inside packageA* that says "Hey! Don't use this source code, go use the linked binary for this instead!"

To do this, we want to *replace* the source code contents in packageA with a file that looks like the following:

```
//go:binary-only-package

package packageA
```

Now, all we need to do to build `main.go` is just to use plain old `go build main.go` and we're all done.

Comment: My directory now is as your answer.  packageA is a static  link library. I don't have it's source code.

Comment: What happens if you do `go tool compile -I lib/ main.go -D $GOPATH/src/project`?

Comment: It also get error: can't find import "project/packageB".

Comment: And if you just refer to it as packageB?

Comment: If I use go build,  it can find packageB but not find packageA. If I use go tool compile, it can find packageA but can't find packageB.

Comment: Can you push up a small github repo to use as an example?

Comment: https://github.com/minusy/demo     I installed packageA then generated packageA.a in $GOPATH/pkg/linux_amd64.  And remove src/packageA. Then I do: go tool compile -I $GOPATH/pkg/linux_amd64 main.go. Get error: can't find import: "packageB"

Comment: @Minusy I have updated my answer with a semi-extensive walkthrough showing how to build and compile against a statically linked binary as well as go source in the same build step. Thank you for the GitHub project, I actually learned a lot answering your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely.  Your answer is a perfect solution to my problem. This is the first time I ask questions on Stack Overflow. And my English is so bad that I can't describe my problem very well. Thank you again for you help.